# Refactor Fields error QGIS 2.16

Tags: fields-attributes, qgis-2.16

I am using Refactor fields from the Processing toolbox, since Table manager gives me a warning not to use it anymore.
I only want to change the order of the columns/fields in a small table.

Using Refactor fields gives the error below. 
Can someone help me solve this?

"An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.
File"C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmDialog.py", line 290, in closeEvent QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layerWasAdded.disconnect(self.mainWidget.layerAdded)
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not connected

Comment: I even switched to 2.14 now, which I newly installed. It yields the same problems..

Comment: What data format is your layer? Shapefile, csv etc?

Comment: It's a normal shape file

Comment: Do you have a _processing_ folder in your `/.qgis2/python/plugins/` directory? If so, delete it and restart QGIS and try again.

Comment: Not in /.qgis2/python/plugins/, but directly in my /.qgis2/ directory. Is that the same?

Comment: No, that one can stay. Could you upload your shapefile to a public server so that others could test it? Or a sample of it as there may be an issue with the data?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29291591/TEST.zip

Comment: Works fine, the output is correct when moving the columns. You're right in that the message does appear (I didn't turn the python console on when testing). Is your output not correct or are you wondering why there is an error message?

Comment: Thanks for checking! I wonder why I get the error message, and since I work with many data sets of 10000+ records, I'm not eager to need to check every time if my output is correct. Error messages stress me ;-)

Comment: I understand, I don't particularly like seeing red writing either ;). It seems the error is coming from another script "AlgorithmDialog.py", more specifically in the `closeEvent()` function. This function tries to disconnect the tool's window from the layer that was used. I think when you run the tool and it closes, the `closeEvent()` function is initiated but for some reason fails. So I think the **actual refactoring** works perfectly fine. Hopefully an expert can post an answer and put your mind at easy ;)